# Fancybox causes my other <a href's to mess up

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

I want to know how to apply my fancybox only to one a tag and not all of my a tags, cause they get messed up. Is there someway to stop the code, so it doesn't mess up the rest of the a tags on the page. Or maybe set the fancybox to only work on one a tag id.

This is my fancybox script on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.group").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'    :    'elastic',
        'transitionOut'    :    'elastic',
        'speedIn'        :    600, 
        'speedOut'        :    200, 
        'overlayShow'    :    false,
    });

});
```

This is my HTML code (probably irrelevant):

```
<a class="group" rel="group1" href="myimagepath">
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you forgot to add closing tag `</a>`

Comment: fancybox js files does so my a href doesnt work besides the one where fancybox is valid. If you know how to stop javascript from running further down a page please tell me as that could solve my problem. I only want the script to work on one a tag. So if i could stop fancybox from running after the a tag that would solve the problem. And no its not that i forgot to add a closing tag

Comment: There must be something with your html; or you are using wp and forgot that you have some other lightbox plugin enabled; or ..... there are tons of possible causes, but the script itself is none of them. And again, since you did not provide a demo, it is just impossible to help you.